# Query para comparar varios campos de una misma tabla

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo esta tabla:

```
+----+------------+-----------+
| ID | VALID_FROM | VALID_TO  |
+----+------------+-----------+
| A  | 28-JUN-19  | 28-JUN-19 |
+----+------------+-----------+
| A  | 28-JUN-19  | 29-JUN-19 | //penultimo de A
+----+------------+-----------+
| A  | 28-JUN-19  | 30-JUN-19 | //ultimo de A
+----+------------+-----------+
| B  | 28-JUN-19  | 30-JUN-19 | // lo ignoramos
+----+------------+-----------+
| C  | 27-JUN-19  | 28-JUN-19 |
+----+------------+-----------+
| C  | 28-JUN-19  | 28-JUN-19 |
+----+------------+-----------+
| C  | 28-JUN-19  | 29-JUN-19 |
+----+------------+-----------+
| C  | 29-JUN-19  | 30-JUN-19 | //penultimo de C
+----+------------+-----------+
| C  | 29-JUN-19  | 01-JUL-19 | //ultimo de C
+----+------------+-----------+
```

Necesito una query que por cada grupo presente `A,B,C` me regrese los records en los que el `VALID_FROM` de el ultimo elemento de un grupo es MAYOR al `VALID_TO` de el penultimo elemento de ese mismo grupo`.

Si un grupo tiene una sola fila entonces no se hace la comparación (COMO EN EL CASO DE B).

La query que he creado es esta:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    myTabla g1
INNER JOIN
    myTabla g2 ON g2.valid_from > g1.valid_to 
WHERE
    g1.ID = g2.ID;
```

No se si la logica es correcta, y nose como hacer la comparación solo entre los últimos y penúltimos de cada grupo.

Comment: ¿`GIU` es Junio?

Comment: Si, editare y pondre JUN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener el último y penúltimo registro por [ID], se requiere un campo para ordenarlos, en este caso utilice la columna [N_REGISTRO] con un número correlativo, podría ser también un campo datetime.

En el ejemplo de la consulta no hay registros que cumplan la condición solicitada, por lo que se ingreso el grupo "D" en los datos de ejemplo de esta respuesta.

```
-- PASO 1: CREAR TABLA TEMPORAL CON EL CAMPO [N_BY_ID] PARA IDENTIFICAR EL ÚLTIMO (N_BY_ID=1) Y PENÚLTIMO (N_BY_ID=2) REGISTRO POR [ID].
SELECT *
INTO #TB_TEMPORAL
FROM
(
    SELECT [N_REGISTRO]
          ,[ID]
          ,[VALID_FROM]
          ,[VALID_TO]
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY N_REGISTRO ASC) AS N_BY_ID --IDENTIFICA EL ULTIMO (N_BY_ID=1) Y PENÚLTIMO (N_BY_ID=2) REGISTRO POR [ID].
      FROM [dbo].[myTabla]
     --ORDER BY [N_REGISTRO] DESC
 ) AS TB
 WHERE TB.N_BY_ID < 3 -- FILTRO PARA OBTENER SOLO LOS ÚLTIMOS Y PENÚLTIMOS REGISTROS POR [ID].

-- PASO 2: OBTENER LOS REGISTRO QUE CUMPLEN LA CONDICIÓN SOLICITADA.
SELECT TB1.*
FROM #TB_TEMPORAL TB1, #TB_TEMPORAL TB2 --CROSS JOIN CON SIGO MISMA.
WHERE TB1.VALID_FROM > TB2.VALID_TO -- FILTRA SOLO LOS CASOS DONDE [VALID_FROM] ES MAYOR QUE [VALID_TO].
      AND TB1.N_BY_ID = 1 -- FILTRA LOS ÚLTIMOS REGISTROS DE TB1.
      AND TB2.N_BY_ID = 2 -- FILTRA LOS PENÚLTIMOS REGISTROS DE TB2.
      AND TB1.ID = TB2.ID -- FILTRA LOS REGISTROS CON IGUAL [ID].

-- DATOS DE EJEMPLO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myTabla](
    [N_REGISTRO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ID] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [VALID_FROM] [date] NOT NULL,
    [VALID_TO] [date] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[myTabla] ([N_REGISTRO], [ID], [VALID_FROM], [VALID_TO]) VALUES (8, N'A         ', CAST(0xD53F0B00 AS Date), CAST(0xD63F0B00 AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[myTabla] ([N_REGISTRO], [ID], [VALID_FROM], [VALID_TO]) VALUES (7, N'A         ', CAST(0xD53F0B00 AS Date), CAST(0xD73F0B00 AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[myTabla] ([N_REGISTRO], [ID], [VALID_FROM], [VALID_TO]) VALUES (6, N'B         ', CAST(0xD53F0B00 AS Date), CAST(0xD73F0B00 AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[myTabla] ([N_REGISTRO], [ID], [VALID_FROM], [VALID_TO]) VALUES (5, N'C         ', CAST(0xD43F0B00 AS Date), CAST(0xD53F0B00 AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[myTabla] ([N_REGISTRO], [ID], [VALID_FROM], [VALID_TO]) VALUES (4, N'C         ', CAST(0xD53F0B00 AS Date), CAST(0xD53F0B00 AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[myTabla] ([N_REGISTRO], [ID], [VALID_FROM], [VALID_TO]) VALUES (3, N'C         ', CAST(0xD53F0B00 AS Date), CAST(0xD63F0B00 AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[myTabla] ([N_REGISTRO], [ID], [VALID_FROM], [VALID_TO]) VALUES (2, N'C         ', CAST(0xD63F0B00 AS Date), CAST(0xD73F0B00 AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[myTabla] ([N_REGISTRO], [ID], [VALID_FROM], [VALID_TO]) VALUES (1, N'C         ', CAST(0xD63F0B00 AS Date), CAST(0xD83F0B00 AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[myTabla] ([N_REGISTRO], [ID], [VALID_FROM], [VALID_TO]) VALUES (9, N'D         ', CAST(0xDE3F0B00 AS Date), CAST(0xDF3F0B00 AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[myTabla] ([N_REGISTRO], [ID], [VALID_FROM], [VALID_TO]) VALUES (10, N'D         ', CAST(0xDC3F0B00 AS Date), CAST(0xDD3F0B00 AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[myTabla] ([N_REGISTRO], [ID], [VALID_FROM], [VALID_TO]) VALUES (11, N'D         ', CAST(0xDB3F0B00 AS Date), CAST(0xDC3F0B00 AS Date))

GO
```

Comment: Funcionaria si uso el id como [GRUPO]?

Comment: Claro, pero edite la respuesta manteniendo el nombre de la columna.